# How to Insert a command to run before Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, Cinnamon, sleeps

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, sleep

I am using Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, with Cinnamon on a laptop.

(I believe Cinnamon is a fork of Gnome).

In the system settings I have set the laptop to sleep after 20 minutes of inactivity.

I wish to be able to issue a command to turn the printer off just before the computer sleeps.

How / where can I insert such a command?

Comment: I have discovered I can do this with  `gnome-terminal -x sh -c curl http://192.168.1.50/?s2-1off && echo password | sudo -S pm-suspend` though I am having difficulty getting the right format for the gnome-terminal command structure for sequential commands. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should add this as an edit to your post. Also include the output/error you see when you try to run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it can be done

In Cinnamon

1. Open system settings
2. Choose Keyboard
3. Choose Keyboard Shortcuts
4. Choose Custom Shortcuts
5. Choose Add Custom Shortcut
6. Enter name as "Printer off and Sleep"
7. Enter comand as

   gnome-terminal -x bash -c "curl http://192.168.1.50/?s2-1off; echo password | sudo -S pm-suspend"
8. Press Add.
9. Double click a keyboard binding to assign shortcut key pattern. In my case Windows key +

`

Done!